# While Checking Lightning Readiness, report says Window used at line 7, in jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom/js/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.js

Tags: visualforce, lightning, salesforce1-app, lightning-experience

How can i change Jquery UI Script,Same is the issue with Jquery DataTable Script and Jquery as well.Problem is Shown in `<apex:includeScript value="XXXXXXX ">`

Answer (score 0):

You will need to get rid of JQuery for lightning components. It's due to the [LockerService](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2016/04/introducing-lockerservice-lightning-components.html). Read [This](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2017/02/lockerservice-lightning-container-third-party-libraries-lightning-components.html) to learn more about using third party libaries